# Mail: How to send message from selected account

Tags: mail.app, mojave

I'm using Apple Mail version 12.4 running on macOS Mojave. I have configured it with several email accounts.

When creating a new message, the sender's email is automatically selected. Mail's Preferences offer only two options:

1. Always use the email associated with a given account of your choice.
2. select the email automatically (the email is chosen based on a supposed *intelligent guess*).

Neither option 1 nor 2 works well for me.

**Question:** Is there any way to let Mail.app automatically use the email associated with the currently selected account (the one in the vertical sidebar on left) as sender?

In the past (before macOS Sierra) that's how Mail used to work. I'm seeking a way to restore that behaviour.

Comment: how does 1. above differ from your desire?

Comment: @jmh with option nr. 1 you select a single account (from the list of all the configured accounts) and every email is sent from that email address - I want Mail to select the sender email based on the active account at the time I create a new message